# Scrapy - pymongo not inserting items to DB

Tags: python, scrapy, pymongo

So im playing about with scrapy trying to learn, and using MongoDB as my DB ive come to a dead end.
Basically the scraping works as the items im fetching are showing in the terminal log, but i cant get the data to publish on my DB. The MONGO_URI is correct as i tried it in the python shell where i can create and store data..

Here are my files

items.py

```
import scrapy

class MaterialsItem(scrapy.Item):
    # define the fields for your item here like:
    # name = scrapy.Field()
    title = scrapy.Field()
    price = scrapy.Field()
   ## url = scrapy.Field()
    pass
```

spider.py

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.selector import Selector

from ..items import MaterialsItem

class mySpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "<placeholder for post>"
    allowed_domains = ["..."]
    start_urls = [
   ...
    ]

    def parse(self, response):
        products = Selector(response).xpath('//div[@class="content"]')

        for product in products:        
                item = MaterialsItem()
                item['title'] = product.xpath("//a[@class='product-card__title product-card__title-v2']/text()").extract(),
                item['price'] = product.xpath("//div[@class='product-card__price-value ']/text()").extract()
               ## product['url'] = 
                yield item
```

settings.py

```
MONGO_PIPELINES = {
    'materials.pipelines.MongoPipeline': 300,
}


#setup mongo DB
MONGO_URI = "my MongoDB Atlas address"
MONGO_DB = "materials"
```

pipelines.py

```
import pymongo

class MongoPipeline(object):

    collection_name = 'my-prices'

    def __init__(self, mongo_uri, mongo_db):
        self.mongo_uri = mongo_uri
        self.mongo_db = mongo_db

    @classmethod
    def from_crawler(cls, crawler):
        ## pull in information from settings.py
        return cls(
            mongo_uri=crawler.settings.get('MONGO_URI'),
            mongo_db=crawler.settings.get('MONGO_DB', ', <placeholder-spider name>')

        )

    def open_spider(self, spider):
        ## initializing spider
        ## opening db connection
        self.client = pymongo.MongoClient(self.mongo_uri)
        self.db = self.client[self.mongo_db]

    def close_spider(self, spider):
        ## clean up when spider is closed
        self.client.close()

    def process_item(self, item, spider):
        ## how to handle each post
        self.db[self.collection_name].insert(dict(item))
        logging.debug("Post added to MongoDB")
        return item
```

Any help would be great!

**Edit

file structure

```
materials
  spiders
  my-spider
items.py
pipelines.py
settings.py
```

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't the line in the MongoPipeline class:

```
collection_name = 'my-prices'
```

be:

```
self.collection_name = 'my-prices'
```

since you call:

```
self.db[self.collection_name].insert(dict(item))
```

Comment: Although this seems correct, it does not work in this example for me.. This is the scrapy example for pipeline to mongodb which i have just edited with my own data. i tried adding `self.colection_name` as you suggested but i breaks the code.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, with a fresh head i looked over everything again. Turns out in settings i had to edit the

```
MONGO_PIPELINES = {
    'materials.pipelines.MongoPipeline': 300,
}
```

to

```
ITEM_PIPELINES = {
    'materials.pipelines.MongoPipeline': 300,
}
```

I guess i shouldnt have changed the naming format, from ITEM_PIPELINES to MONGO_PIPELINES.

Answer (score 0):

what the code error and i think i need to beunder **init** if it posible can you upload it to git ? and i might try to have a look

Comment: Thanks but as above i think my issue is resolved, was a misnamed rule in settings :)